# Navigating XML based on the last node you processed in Python

Tags: python, xml, graph-theory

In Python I am trying to navigate XML (nodes) and creating links/traversing through nodes based on the last node you processed, I have a set of source and target nodes where i have to traverse from Source to Target and then from Target to Source and then same again, it may have same nodes multiples times as well.

Attached the XML structure below

```
targetNode="FCMComposite_1_2" sourceNode="FCMComposite_1_1"
targetNode="FCMComposite_1_4" sourceNode="FCMComposite_1_5"
targetNode="FCMComposite_1_6" sourceNode="FCMComposite_1_5"
targetNode="FCMComposite_1_8" sourceNode="FCMComposite_1_2"
targetNode="FCMComposite_1_2" sourceNode="FCMComposite_1_9"
targetNode="FCMComposite_1_3" sourceNode="FCMComposite_1_8"
targetNode="FCMComposite_1_5" sourceNode="FCMComposite_1_3"
```

In the XML above, I have to start from the 1st SourceNode (FCMComposite_1_1) to the 1st TargetNode (FCMComposite_1_2), then I have to navigate from this TargetNode (Last Node) to the SourceNode having the same value, in this case the 4th row, then from there to the destination Node and so on.

What is the best way to Achieve this? is Graph a good option for this, I am trying this in Python. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary to store the connections. What you posted isn't actually XML, so I just use `re` to parse it, but you can do the parsing differently.

```
import re

data = '''
targetNode="FCMComposite_1_2" sourceNode="FCMComposite_1_1"
targetNode="FCMComposite_1_4" sourceNode="FCMComposite_1_5"
targetNode="FCMComposite_1_6" sourceNode="FCMComposite_1_5"
targetNode="FCMComposite_1_8" sourceNode="FCMComposite_1_2"
targetNode="FCMComposite_1_2" sourceNode="FCMComposite_1_9"
targetNode="FCMComposite_1_3" sourceNode="FCMComposite_1_8"
targetNode="FCMComposite_1_5" sourceNode="FCMComposite_1_3"
'''

beginning = None
connections = {}
for line in data.split('\n'):
    m = re.match(r'targetNode="([^"]+)" sourceNode="([^"]+)"', line)
    if m:
        target = m.group(1)
        source = m.group(2)
        if beginning is None:
            beginning = source
        connections[source] = target

print('Starting at', beginning)
current = beginning
while current in connections.keys():
    print(current, '->', connections[current])
    current = connections[current]
```

Output:

```
Starting at FCMComposite_1_1
FCMComposite_1_1 -> FCMComposite_1_2
FCMComposite_1_2 -> FCMComposite_1_8
FCMComposite_1_8 -> FCMComposite_1_3
FCMComposite_1_3 -> FCMComposite_1_5
FCMComposite_1_5 -> FCMComposite_1_6
```

I'm not sure whats's supposed to happen with the multiple targets for `FCMComposite_1_5`.

Comment: If a source has multiple targets, a simple dictionary is not enough. You can change dictionary value type to be a list. It's called adjacency list representation.